# Can Hibernate be notified/see when manual CRUD operations are made?

Tags: java, sql, database, hibernate

I have the following setup:

- a legacy db
- a Java + Hibernate application reading from this legacy db
- there are cases when the db is manually updated

Is there a way (e.g. a Hibernate functionality) to have Hibernate notified if a CRUD operation is manually made on that db (via some SQL script)? if there's nothing built-in in in Hibernate for this, would there be a clean, decent way to achieve this?

Thank you.

Comment: What would hibernate be notified look like? I mean, what should hibernate do to react?

Comment: DatabaseChangeRegistration would be your best bet. Have a look at this link[https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/dbchgnf.htm#JJDBC28818]